# Placing $L$-shaped tiles on $2\times n$ checkerboard

Tags: combinatorics, recursion, tiling

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider a $2\times n$ checkerboard. Let $a_n$ be the number of ways to place $L$-shaped tiles (of size $4$) on the checkerboard. For example, all possible ways for $n=4$ is $a_4=11$. Also, it can be checked that $a_5=19$ . Find a recursive formula for $a_n$ and use it to compute $a_8$.

Here placing no tile counts as one of the possible ways. The size of the tile is fixed.

The recursive formula is of the form $$a_n=Aa_{n−1}+Ba_{n−3}+Ca_{n−4}+Da_{n−5}$$ , $\forall n≥6$,
for some non-zero integers ${A,B,C,D}$.

Comment: I am at loss how you can place two L-shaped  tiles of size $4$ on the $2\times 4$ board in $11$ ways... Either I am imagining it wrong, or there are just two ways. Does some sort of picture go with this problem?

Comment: @StinkingBishop you don't have to fill the whole board here.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yep, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are all the possible indecomposable ways to extend a tiling:

[image]

We see that $(A,B,C,D)=(1,4,2,2)$ and can work out $a_8=207$. This is [A337492](https://oeis.org/A337492) in the OEIS.